# Recalculating columns on jQuery .fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I dynamically create bootstrap 4 columns based on an array length. My array has 4 objects in it so it is printing 4 col-sm-3s.

That is being accomplished with this js:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allChars.length; i++) {
    var num = Math.floor(12 / allChars.length);
    $('#allCharsRow').append("<div class='col-sm-" + num + "' id='char-col" + i + "' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='" + allChars[i].toolTipTitle + "'><div class='card'><div class='card-header text-center text-white'> <h4 class='display-6'>" + allChars[i].class + "</h4></div>" + allChars[i].mainGif + "<div class='card-footer'><button class='btn btn-link text-white btn-block' id='charBTN" + i + "'>Choose " + allChars[i].class + "</button></div></div></div></div>")
}
```

That is all well and good until one of the objects is selected. I have a .fadeOut on button click.

```
$('#char-col0').fadeOut('slow');
```

So whichever column is chosen, that whole column disappears. Then the row recalculates and it doesn't look as good. Is there a way I can get the row to not recalculate - i.e. meaning can I get it to think there's still a column there but hide the contents of that column from the user?

I've tried not creating the columns dynamically. I've tried .hide('slow') instead of fadeOut...

Answer (score 0):

`.hide()` transitions the element's CSS to `display: none`, which means it is completely removed from the page.  What you really want to do is keep the element on the page (so that it keeps taking up space), but make it invisible to the user.  In other words, you want to change its opacity to 0:

```
.fadeTo( "slow", 0 )
```

Here is the full API reference: https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/